# mkdir() permission denied codeigniter

Tags: php, macos, codeigniter

I am trying to create a directory with PHP mkdir function but I get an error as follows: 
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tiki-id/system/core/Log.php on line 122

this is the line 122:

```html
file_exists($this->_log_path) OR mkdir($this->_log_path, 0777, TRUE);
```

I put my temp_sess folder on 'Mac/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tiki-id/temp_sess'

and my config.php :

```html
$config['sess_save_path'] = './temp_sess/';
```

my temp_sess folder:

[image: temp_sess info folder]

What did I do wrong?

I'm on mac, web server xampp..

Answer (score 5):

For the first time `$this->log_path` path is not exist

1--> Go to `application/config/config.php` and check the `log_path`. By default  `log_path = application/logs/`

```js
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Error Logging Directory Path
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
  | application/logs/ directory. Use a full server path with trailing slash.
  |
 */
$config['log_path'] = '';
```

2--> Create a new folder named `logs` inside `application`

3--> Give permission 777 to `logs` folder(Command: `chmod 777 logs`)

Hope it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Check for folder permission.It is write protected. Try to give 777 permission to that folder

Comment: right-click on that folder, then change the permission into Read & Write

Comment: Again check for the permission.I am quite sure permission is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, came across this same issue but the problem was we has set the `$config['log_path']` = {a path that could not be found}.  We added the path and updated the permissions and error went away.